# Trying to update 640k rows in mySQL gets "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to execute this line from my seeds.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE bairros SET created_at = (SELECT NOW());")
```

My table called "bairros" has 643k lines and as soon as it reaches this file on the `rake db:seed` command, it throws this error

```
    Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: UPDATE bairros SET created_at = (SELECT NOW());
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `query'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/projetos/AnuncieImoveis/releases/20131015210221/db/seeds.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:153:in `load_seed'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@thedoors/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I really have no idea how to fix this. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: In general, updating many rows in DB at once is not recommended.

For example, if your database server is a master (where the clients can write) and it has many slaves (from where the clients can read), then changing a lot of data might result in replication delay, when the data on slaves become inconsistent with the data on master because it can not update all of them quickly.

The practical advice is to split your data in chunks (500-1000 records at most) and send them to the database chunk-by-chunk. You can do several chunks in parallel, if the order in the table does not matter.

Comment: It's also possible, based on the underlying table type, MySQL May be failing, for example an innodb buffer pool which is to small can limit transaction/query size.

Comment: This is happening on the seed of my database. I'm not updating a large quantity of rows on a database that's being used. This will only happen once and I need it to change to the specified value.

Comment: First thing to do is run the query from the mysql console, and check whether it completes. Or you could think to yourself, seeing as they are all the same value, why am I storing it 643,000 times?

Comment: This was just an example. I need to fetch an ID from a different table and store it as well in this table with 643k records. So I need to do this. 

Another thing is, if I run this on my machine in development mode, the seed completes correctly. In production, on a server with 512mb of RAM, the error is thrown. I think this has to do with the fact of limited memory

Comment: Not sure why you're using a scalar subquery, here... SET created_at = NOW () is sufficient and could be dramatically changing the query plan since the MySQL optimizer is probably treating it as correlated, even though it isn't.

Answer (score 9):

There is another potential reason for this error, and that is the ActiveRecord connection pool [reaper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool/Reaper.html). When enabled, the reaper scans the connection pool for "dead" connections and closes them. In my testing, it appears to be overzealous and closes perfectly alive connections too (generally ones running slightly bigger queries).

Try clearing `reaping_frequency` from your DB config (which turns it off) and see if that helps.  Scan your codebase for that string, and make sure it's unset (or simply removed!). If you see a line like `config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10`, know that the `|| 10` is actually setting a low default of 10s. This pattern was in the rails codebase for a time, until the change was [reverted](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7150a9dc036ca02e8293d31ac57a26c55860fff7) due to it causing various issues, including [killing long running queries](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9907), but is still [recommended by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#threaded-servers).

If disabling the reaper fixes things, I would recommend leaving it disabled. Rails no longer sets it by default, and it seems to cause more problems than it solves.

I had an error like yours, and that was how I fixed it. Personally, I am keeping it disabled. I wrote about my specific problem in more detail on my [blog](http://omegadelta.net/2014/03/15/the-rails-grim-reaper/).

Answer (score 1):

"Lost connection to MySQL server during query" means that either:
1. The database crashed while running the query (can be due to restart, table corruption, etc).
2. The session disconnected due to query timeout (check variable wait_timeout and interactive_timeout depending on your connection type), network problem, someone\something killing your query.

Comment: 3. In rails, it can be caused when the connection was reaped by the connection pool reaper. See my answer.