# MySQL2 Gem: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm experiencing the following exception:

```
in `query': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (Mysql2::Error)
```

It's very difficult to replicate. When I execute the same MySQL Command manually it might work without any problem.

I have narrowed it down as follows:

1.) I **might** get this exception when I select a lot of records from a big table.
   e.g. I have a database with 10million records (and ~50 columns) and I'm getting this error when I select 100k records in one query.

2.) When I do 1.) repeatedly for e.g. 10 times it seems to be more likely that I will get this exception, even when I use new MySQL connections with each query.

I have pasted my MySQL Variables here: http://pastebin.com/D5tfF8Tf

EDIT: I noticed that MySQL is constantly running at ~40% CPU Usage

```
mysql    22811 40.9  0.3 4281712 244212 ?      Ssl  Oct31 2909:26 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Comment: Where's your MYSQL database hosted?

Comment: Hmm okay - have you tried setting up a DB on a host somewhere? It might be a problem with your local MYSQL installation?

Comment: Can there something wrong with MySQL besides bad configuration?
Do you see something wrong with the config? (http://pastebin.com/D5tfF8Tf) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ActiveRecord / Ruby on Rails?

There are a few reasons for this error message, and some suggest tweaking MySQL settings like timeouts, etc – but there is one reason that can be specifically caused by Rails and that is the ActiveRecord connection reaper (enabled by setting the `reaping_frequency` config to non-nil).  If enabled, it seems to randomly kill longer running queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423893/72176

After tweaking just about every MySQL setting I could find that seemed halfway relevant to this issue, it was disabling the connection reaper that fixed it for me.